# Should we use IE's CSS Dynamic properties?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, browser, css-expressions

Should we use IE's CSS Dynamic properties?

I read IE8+ would not support these.

What is the best strategy to handle this?

Comment: @Warren Young thanks for fix & tag.

Comment: Firefox just announced another breakthrough "innovation" - support for dynamic properties, except they are using `calc()` instead of `expression()` - http://mzl.la/9f9g7x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean CSS expressions, you should avoid them because they're [slow](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_expressions).

Your question about how to avoid them is pretty vague.  It would be easier to answer a more specific question.  But here's a vague answer: Javascript. :)

Answer (score 1):

They are very useful to solve incompatibility problems with older versions of IE, for example to get png transparency in IE6. I always (when needed...) include style-sheets using these functionalities in IE's conditional comments.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic properties wasn't anything that really took off. It could be used in applications that targeted IE only (i.e. intranets and such), but as it never became a standard and no other browser supports it, it never came into wide use on the web.

I haven't read what you say about IE8 not supporting dynamic properties, and I haven't tried it, but it sounds very plausible that the will not be supported when the browser renders a page in standards compliant mode. They will probably be supported in quirks mode for a few versions longer.